# Haproxy does not recognize request header

Tags: haproxy

Request header passed through HAProxy but `hdr()`, `req.hdr()` or any relevant function does not recognize any request header although it's passed to target server.

My front-end config as below with http mode:

```
acl xip req.hdr(x-real-ip) -m found 
use_backend first-half if xip
```

Not working! Although this header is present.

N.B: Only `req(host)` is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "X-Forwarded-For" in place of "x-real-ip".